# Database normalisation (1NF to 3NF)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-normalization

I'm currently doing some coursework where I have been given a suggested table where I have to identify which normal form rules it would break. Which I think I have done, but I have been getting confused when to apply certain rules. So I would be grateful if someone could check it and explain to me why things are wrong if there is any.

Example:

[image: UNF]

This would break 1NF as there is duplicate data as each photographer may attend multiple matches (Matches ID) hence to solve this and bring to 1NF I do this:

[image: 1NF and 2NF]

As there is no composite key it is already in 2NF for both tables, however there are transitive dependencies between company and company number. Therefore do this to bring to 3NF:

[image: 3nf]

Is Mobile No and Photo Name also a transitive dependency? If someone has the same name it would mean it is not? Also I'm unsure if I would have classified the Company and Company number as duplicates when taking it to 1NF.

Thanks.

---

EDIT: note, Sorry for the confusion - PhotoID is the Photographers ID. Full column names:

`Photographer ID (Primary key) <- Told this is the PK in the question`

```
Photographer Name,

Mobile Phone Number,

Employing Company, <-Told this is unique in the question

Employing Company Phone Number,

Matches Attending,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 2nd image, you skipped the traditional 1NF treatment of repeating groups (duplicating the grouped data into separate rows for each `Matches ID`) and went straight to 2NF.  No problem there.  Your 3NF is correct as well.

> Is Mobile No and Photo Name also a transitive dependency?

No.  The photographer's name and mobile phone number are attributes (functional dependencies) of the photographer's ID.

> I'm unsure if I would have classified the Company and Company number as duplicates when taking it to 1NF.

Identifying duplicates isn't part of converting a table to 1NF.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem, I think, is that as far as I can see you don't really have an identifier for a person.  The closest you have there is the name. That can give you problems but it passes, I think, the definition of 3NF in this case.

The big issue is you probably want to be able to identify two different individuals named 'John James' so the actual problem is that you need some sort of other information to do that (for example, a social security number, an employee id or the like).  At that point then name needs to be broken off and stored with the identifier for a person (because then the dependency person number is a function of id, but name is a function of person number).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - PhotoID is the Photographers ID. I'll update the question to be more clear.

Comment: In that case it sounds like this is 3NF because the name is always a dependency of the photographer ID.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have learned till date. There must not be any functional dependency in the table to make it pass the 3NF test.

If there is any column in the table that can work at place of primary key then it must not be there.

Now look at the table after normalization - mobile number for sure is a unique id.

Comment: So your suggesting it should be like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/uhi9q.png? - Sorry dont know how to show it in the comment.

Comment: Phones numbers aren't identifiers because people do share phones, even mobile.

Comment: depends on the use case to be honest. I have never deployed a system that allowed users to have duplicate entries of mobile numbers. And I was talking about mobile numbers only.